# Disable GZIP compression for IE6 clients

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7, internet-explorer-6, compression

We need to conditionally disable GZIP compression if user's browser is IE6 (it hangs browser for 5min) in few pages of larger site. Server is IIS7 and has compression for static content turned on - want that compression left working if user agent is not Mozilla/4.0. ASPX code sample anyone? 
Alternatively, code to conditionally redirect to the same page on another site (could create another virtual site with compression disabled) but need to pass all parameters (GET/POST).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try intercepting the browser's request to stop claiming support for Gzip, if the request is from IE5/IE6 .  I believe ISAPI rewrite is available for IIS.

Take note: this does not require you to have separate gzipped and non-gzipped pages.  This is probably a better approach than your proposal, since it cuts the problem at its source.

Comment: Excellent idea. Downloading ISAPI_Rewrite Lite and trying shortly. The only concern with ISAPI filters I have that without source code I can't be sure if 'creator' is not doing something silly that crashes web server or slows down response. But I like the idea - worth a try.